# JS CSS Toggle Button doesn't move up

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The problem is, my open button doesn't want to go on top after being hidden. It remains in the same position!
https://fiddle.jshell.net/4fs5x0p4/

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
    $(function(){
    $("#open").toggle(
      function () {
          $('#navibar').animate({height: "-50px"});
      },
      function () {
        $('#navibar').animate({height: "50px"});
      }
    );

    });//]]> 

    </script>
    <div id="navibar">
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">WordPress</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Themes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Plugins</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Tutorials</a></li>
                    </ul>        
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="open"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button remains in the same position because it is not nested/part of the navibar block and because its position is absolute.

I'm guessing you want something like this:
https://fiddle.jshell.net/4fs5x0p4/1/

this is the script:

```
$(function() {
  $("#open").toggle(
    function() {
      $('#navibar').animate({
        height: "-50px"
      }, 800);
      $(this).css("top", "0px");
    },
    function() {
      $('#navibar').animate({
        height: "50px"
      }, 500);
      $(this).css("top", "30px");
    }
  );
});
```

and I added `transition: top 0.5s ease-out;` to #open styles.
Fine tune the transition and the animation time to your liking.